# displaying issue when switching between RTL and LTR in Win Form Rich Text Box

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, right-to-left

I tried the same thing in both Win form and WPF form and seems this only happens in Win Form. 
Basically what's happening is that I have a RTB control in Win Form, and 2 buttons: RTL and LTR to adjust the alignment.

button1 clicked:

```
richTextBox1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
```

button2 clicked:

```
richTextBox1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
```

That's all I have. when I paste text into RTB and click on the RTL button, it left a big gap in RTB. I noticed this will ONLY happen if the scroll bar is presenting. if you resize the form, the gap will go away.

see link for the screenshot:
[screenshot of the issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/567213)

I tried everything I could but couldn't figure out why it's happening. I suspect it's a .NET bug, does anybody have any idea?

Comment: just an idea: did you try to refresh the rtb after setting the .RightToLeft property? just do a .Refresh() on the RTB after setting this and see if it helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes, i did try Refresh() but it didn't help.

Comment: where exactly the big gap appears? can you paste a screenshot?

Comment: okay, just use RTB.ScrollToCaret() after you paste your content. it fixed on my app.

Comment: thanks, I tried the following: but it's still not working, in your case RTB is the richTextBox instance?

private void RTL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}

Comment: This is a Windows bug, the version matters.  On Windows 8, the gap is exactly the width of the scrollbar.  Do keep in mind that you are invoking an extremely unusual pattern, actual Windows users don't change their reading preference on the fly of course.  So doing something that nobody ever does certainly has a knack for revealing flaws.  Just don't do this, there's no point to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could get to work is to reset the text when you change the RightToLeft property of the RTB control and adding a Application.Doevents().

Like this:

```
private void buttonRTL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string txtRTF = RichTextBox1.Rtf;
    RichTextBox1.Clear();
    RichTextBox1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
    Application.DoEvents();
    RichTextBox1.Rtf = txtRTF;

}
```

Comment: thanks, this seems resolved the issue. I would consider this as a workaround since I still don't understand why we have to do this. I still think it's a .NET bug

Comment: Instead of DoEvents, you can try: `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.Rtf = txtRTF; }));`